# If $A = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and $I = (2, 1 + \sqrt{-5})$, why is $I \otimes_A I \cong A?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, flatness

I just finished an exam where this was the final question. I could not for the life of me figure out how to do this. My first guess was to use the fact that there is a surjective homomorphism $I \otimes I \to I^2$ but this doesn't work since $I$ is proper and $I^2 \subset I$. My next idea was to work backward to find a homomorphism $\phi: A \to I \otimes I$ by determining $\phi(1)$. Expanding out $$(2a + (1 + \sqrt{-5})b) \otimes (2\alpha + (1 + \sqrt{-5})\beta)$$ did not yield a simple expression which suggested a simple generator. This is where my time essentially ran out so I resorted to trying $\phi(1) = 2 \otimes (1 + \sqrt{-5}) + (1 + \sqrt{-5}) \otimes 2$ but this idea didn't really pan out. Is there something big I'm missing here? I'm still having a lot of trouble seeing what I was supposed to do.

Thank you in advance for you help.

Comment: The map $I\otimes_AI\to I^2$ is an isomorphism in this case as $I$ is flat.

Comment: And $I^2 =2A$, so $I \otimes I \cong 2A \cong A$.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1521552/how-do-you-square-an-ideal) seems to suggest that you're right. $I^2 = \langle 2 \rangle$ which is principle and thus isomorphic to $A$. I wish I would have found this during the exam.